# Deducing Young Tableaux from symmetries

Tags: group-representations, representation-theory

I have a particular problem, the following.

$T^{a_1 \dots a_p;b_1 \dots b_p}$ is a tensor with the following symmetries.

1) $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are completely antisymmetric, ie restricted to either$a_i's $ or $ b_i's$

2) Total interchange of $a_i$'s with $b_i$'s are symmetric, that is
$T^{a_1 \dots a_p;b_1 \dots b_p} = T^{b_1 \dots b_p;a_1 \dots a_p}$

Is this an irreducible representation of the full $S_{2p}$ group? if not how to decompose it? And what are/is the associated young tableau.

In general I would be grateful if anyone can provide me with a reference on how to go about finding the associated tableau given arbitrary symmetries, such as cyclic symmetry etc..

I am guessing the usual procedure of the Littlewood-Richardson rule can be constrained further when additional symmetries are present?

Thanks for you help.

---------------------- ADDITIONAL DETAILS --------------------------------

$\textbf {Question 1}$

An arbitrary Tensor $T$ is decomposed into irrep's, ie, it is projected by a young operator. I call one of the projectors, $P_1$. So the tensor corresponding to this particular irrep is given by $T_{irrep_1} = P_1.T$. Now I have some additional information about T, that is a symmetrisation of certain indices vanish. I take this symmetrisation operator to be $\mathbf S$. So the additional information I have is

$\mathbf S.T =0$.

Q1) Does this in general imply $\mathbf S.T_{irrep_1} =0$. For this to be true the two operators should commute, $[P_1, S]=0$. Is this true in general? If this is true, $S.T = 0 \implies S.T_{irrep_1} =0$.

Let me make my question clear by taking an example. HERE EVERYTHING IS DONE IN SYMMETRIC BASIS. Consider $T^{ab,cd}$ symmetric in the comma separated indices. My question is that How do I go about decomposing this one with the additional constraint that $(abc)=0$. So I think of T as the product of two tensors with the symmetry {(ab)X(cd)} and decompose this. That would give me i) {ab,cd} ii){abc,d} iii){abd,c} iv) {abcd} (HERE COMMA SEPARATES THE ROWS). At this point I want to apply the additional constraint $(abc) =0$. and this where my confusion lies. I DO understand that these components do not mix and I can treat them sepearately.

Q) If I assume the additional symmetry is inherited by the each component I will just apply this to i,ii,iii, iv and I indeed see only the component {ab,cd} satisfies. So it somehow works? Does that mean the two projectors always commute? Or It works by someother reason?

Another way to see {ab,cd} is the only one is to decompose using two different ways (symmetric basis)

1) Decomposing ${(ab) X (cd)}$

2) Decomposing ${ab,c X d}$  the right component/s should be whatever that is the intersection of these two operations and I see only the {ab,cd} one is shared by 1) 2). This method- I see why it works. but the previous method is puzzling for me.

**Question 2**

Given $T^{a[p],b[p]} $computing $1^p \otimes 1^p$ gives ${a[p]b[i],b[p-i]}$ with the young condition this tensor corresponds to one of the irreducible representation. I two questions regarding this,

2.1) For the same reason I was confused in question 1, Is saying the tensor T, satisfies condition two, ie, total pairwise interchange of a's and b's is symmetric, imply, the pairwise interchange of an irreducible component symmetric.

2.2) You said that anti-symmetrising over all b's in ${a[p]b[i],b[p-i]}$ yields a tensor satisfying condition one and lies in the same invariant sub-space. I AGREE. but is this the only tensor in this invariant sub-space that satisfies condition one? If I take for example $a[p-1]b[i+1],ab[p-i-1]$ this tensor lies in the invariant subspace. If I antisymmetrise over all b's do I get another independent tensor that satisfied condition 1?

Comment: I do not know the recipe for all possible cases, but for your particular one...  First compute $1^p\otimes 1^p$ to find Young diagrams made of two columns with the first of height $(p+i)$ and the second $p-i$, these all obey 1). Now we try to impose the additional constraint 2) of being symmetric under the exchange of all a's with b's. You can use the Young condition that the anti-symmetrization of all indices corresponding to the first column to one index from the second column vanishes to exchange the two groups. The exchange produces a sign $(-)^i$, so only for even $i$ your 2) is met.

Comment: As an example you can try the totally symmetric rank-$2p$ tensor and see that it obeys 2) when p is even. Another check is for the tensor with the symmetry of $[p,p]$ diagram, i.e. $i=0$, it obeys 2), as it is easy to see. Often such subproblems appear in the study and can be solved just from Young conditions and knowledge of tensor products.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @John. I see what you mean and understand your fist point of computing $1^p X 1^P $. But I don't think interchanging the entries along rows the tensor is invariant. But it is true interchanging the entries in the column the tensor flips sign. Do you agree? I would be grateful for your reply.

Comment: I used the identity $T^{a[k]b[k-i],b[i]}=(-)^iT^{b[k]a[k-i],a[i]}$ with the obvious meaning of condensed notation $a[k]=a_1...a_k$. In principle one can use the symmetric base, where everything is split into pairs of symmetric indices, but this is just less convenient. There is no inconsistency, any computation can be done in any base.

Comment: is $a[k]$ antisymmetric in it's indices? How do you prove this identity? Can you please let me know where you got this from?

Comment: Can you please point me to a reference or paper where they do these sort of manipulation with these notation so I can get an idea. Kind regards.

Comment: yes, $a[k]$ is a group of $k$ anti-symmetric indices. I derived the identity step by step. First, consider the Young condition: $T^{[a[k]b[i],b] b[k-i-1]}\equiv0$ where the enclosing brackets mean antisymmetrization over $k+i+1$ indices. Let us write this as $T^{a[k][b[i],b]b[k-i-1]}+(-)^{(i+1)k}T^{b[i+1][a[k-1],a]b[k-i-1]}\equiv0$. From this we can move one $b$ to the first group of indices and $a$ to the second. Repeating this and being careful about signs, you can derive the identity above. You may look at Appendix A,E of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.2975.pdf but this is mostly about symmetric

Comment: Dear John, Thanks for your help. It's getting more clearer now. The condition $T^{[a[k]b[i],b]b[k-i-1]} = 0$ Do you use comma to separate the entries in the two columns in the young diagram? Why does this mean the second condition in my question is satisfied?

Comment: 2) can be seen to be satisfied for $i$ even from $T^{a[k]b[i],b[k-i]}=(-)^iT^{b[k]a[i],a[k-i]}$, which can be derived step by step from Young condition. Young condition for a tensor of $[k+i,k-i]$ states that anti-symmetrization of first $(k+i)$ indices with at least one more is zero. This was I showed how to use - one can exchange the two groups of indices eventually and see what is the sign cost, if any. Comma indeed separates the two groups of indices

Comment: Dear John, apologise if I am causing inconvenience. I would be grateful if you can answer one more question. In your relation $T^{a[k][b[i],b]}b[k-i-1] + (-)^{(i+1)k} T^{b[i+1][a[k-1],a]b[k-i-1]}=0$, I see that you are shuffling the entire indices $a[k]$ to front and back hence the sign. I don't quite see if this is trivial. Don't I need to consider the index one by one. Example: $[abc] = a[bc] - b[ac] +c[ba]$. Also I see that the young condition means the representation is irreducible, if instead I use the tableaux is this condition automatically imposed, how do I see this? . Thanks so much!

Comment: @John Just to notify you of my comment above. Also I am puzzled when you say that condition one is satisfied for all the decompositions that come from $1^k X 1^k$. For example the tensor that corresponds to the tableaux ${a_1 b_1,a_2 b_2,a_3,b_3}$ with comma separating the rows and which is a product of ${a_1,a_2,a_3} X {b_1,b_2,b_3} $ is not antisymmetric in b's. Even if we follow symmetrize the rows first then antisymetrise the columns rule?

Comment: $a[k]$ means a group of $k$ antisymmetric indices, which means I anti-symmetrize over them each time, but writing sums over permutations of $a_{\sigma(1)}...a_{\sigma(k)}$ would be too time and space consuming. $T^{[ab...,c]d...}\equiv0$ is the Young condition. It is not automatic in some sense, you have to remember how it looks like. Even if the tensor is totally antisymmetric there are conditions it obeys, but they are easy to take into account. If in you last question you mean $[k,k]$ diagram, then yes, it obeys your 2). If you mean the tensor product, then no, I have the answer above.

Comment: In your last comment you used the symmetric basis for tensors. It is ok, but just less convenient for computations with generic $[k+i,k]$ tensor. For $[k,k]$ it is trivial to see in the symmetric basis that it obeys your 2). But imagine using symmetric basis $a,b,c,d,...$ for the $[2k]$ :)

Comment: @John Thanks:). I actually meant antisymmetric basis, for [k+i,k], where some of the b's are in the first column, right?. But in the reducible tensor I started with b's and a's are separately antisymmetric which is not the case for the b's in generic [k+i,k]? Am I right.

Comment: @John Suppose I decompose a tensor say $T^{ab,c} = -T^{ba,c}$. Then I get say the mixed symmetry tensor $F^{ab,c} = -F^{ba,c} $ with young condition $F^{[ab,c]}=0$. If on top of this the tensor T has this additional symmetry $T^{ab,c} = T^{ac,b}$ This means T =0 identically. For this easy problem I can see without using young. but I see that saying T is symmetric in bc does not mean $F^{ab,c}$ is symmetric in bc. So my question is how is the additional symmetry of the tensor T inherited by F. How do you see this in general? Many thanks.

Comment: OK. Take $[k+i,k-i]$ tensor $T^{c[k+i],d[k-i]}$ now I rename the indices to $T^{a[k]b[i],b[k-i]}$ and antisymmetrize over all $b$'s. The result is not zero and it is a tensor that obeys your 1), i.e. it is antisymmetric into two groups $V^{a[k]|b[k]}$. Then I use Young conditions to check the second property. This is the idea I implied above

Comment: @John  Thanks so much for taking me through this. I see. So one needs to anti-symmetrize to get the relevant tensor. So  can we use the fact that the tensor is anti-symmetrized in b's together with the young condition to check condition 2?

Comment: @John I have this problem the simplified version is the tensor $T^{ab,cd}$ is symmetrc in ab and cd seperately. also it obeys the symmetrisation of a,b,c = 0. This tensor is identically 0. Which I saw from elementary methods. If I  wish to see this from irreducible reps. I need to decompose this and show that every component should vanish right? since ab and cd is symmetric I get one component say {abc,d} with young condition {(abc,d)} =0 symmetric basis. If now I impose the condition {(abc)d}=0 I can show that this component is zero. I feel this is not right,

Comment: @John because when I checked for the case I described above..with tensor $F^{ab,c}$. The component does not have the symmetry the tensor T had? Sorry If I am being so dumb.

Comment: $T^{ab,cd}$ that is symmetric in $ab$ and $cd$ and symmetrization $(ab,c)$ vanishes has the symmetry of $[2,2]$ and is NOT zero! actually it has the symmetry of the Riemann tensor in symmetric notation. You can go the usual antisymmetric basis by antisymmetrazing over say $ac$. So please reconsider what you did and you can reread the comments above since there I solved your original problem. I think the problem for you is just lack of experience, you can find some examples in the Appendix I menioned to train yourself

Comment: Oh sorry. I should have said.. it does not have the irreducible component $(abc,d)$. without the the condition that the symmetrisation over $(abc)=0$ it would have such a component. But then again I am puzzled over the following fact. if I say I apply the symmetrisation condition  on the symmetric basis young diagram I indeed get that the component vanishes. But I am puzzled about the following, can I apply a condition that the original reducible tensor had to an irreducible component. This is what I wished to ask you using my example with tensor $F^{ab,c}$

Comment: @John I am grateful for your patience.

Comment: I do not quite understand since you changed to symmetric tensors. If $T^{(ab|c)d}=0$ this implies there is no $abc,d$. But the useful statement is that $T^{ab|cd}$ that is just symmetric into two pairs can be represented as $W^{ab,cd}+V^{ab(c,d)}$ where the components have $(2,2)$ and $(3,1)$ symmetry types. In any case components of different symmetry types do not mix together so you can solve your problem for each of them separately, as I did by decomposing $T^{a[k]|b[k]}$ as $\sum_i T^{a[k]b[i],b[k-i]}$ where the $i$-th tensor has $[k+i,k-i]$ type and $b$ are antisymmetrized to match 1)

Comment: @John, I have made my question a bit more clearer by editing the posted question under the heading 'Additional details'. I have learned quite a bit from you, thanks a lot. Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: 2.2) Your second arrangement of indices is identical to the first one upon using the Young properties, so it does not produce any independent tensor to be considered

Comment: @John Dear John I have a question which I posted here, can you kindly give any insights on this problem please?   http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127650/i-want-to-decompose-a-tensor-product-using-littlewood-richardson-rule-how-do-i