# I want to decompose a tensor product using Littlewood-Richardson rule, How do I find the component of this in each irreducible space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, symmetry, group-representations, representation-theory

Let me set up the notation I am using. $(abc,de)$ denotes the standard Young tableau where the first row is $abc$ and the second row is $de$. Each young tableau corresponds to the young symmetriser, and I use the convention that given the Young tableau $\lambda$ young symmetriser is given by,

$P_{\lambda} = Na.b$ where $a = \sum_{\sigma \in Rowgroup} \sigma$, and  $b = \sum_{\sigma \in Column-group} (sgn \,\sigma) \sigma$. N stands for normaliser such that $P_{\lambda}$ is idempotent ($P_{\lambda}^2 = P_{\lambda}$).

The action of the symmetric group on an abstract tensor is by means of shuffling the indices. I know that the following identity is true.

$\mathbb{1} = \sum_iP_{\lambda_i}$
Here $\lambda_i$ are all the Standard young tableau of a given number of boxes.
Applying this identity to any abstract tensor should give the same tensor back. And if this abstract tensor is completely arbitrary, i.e does not have any symmetries in its indices this decomposition yields components living in each irreps. OK. My question is when we have tensor products, then we use Littlewood-Richardson rule to find a one of the basis tensors representing each irreducible space. However I am interested in not just treating the tensor product as a vector space and finding the disjoint union of irreducible vector spaces, that each young tableau corresponds to and acting with the Young symmetriser yields one of the basis tensors.

I would like to find out the given tensor in each irreducible space. Let me give an example. Suppose I have a rank 3 tensor that is antisymmetric in the first 2 indices. I can treat this as a tensor product of $(a,b) \otimes c$(Here ab is a column as per my notation.) Applying LRH I get, $(ac,b),(a,b,c)$. Using the young symmetriser I defined above, I act with this normalised young symmetriser on the tensor $T^{ab|c}$ (here the bar is used to group anti-symmetric indices). I get,

$T_1^{abc}= P_{ac,b} T^{ab|c} = \frac{2}{3}(T^{ab|c} + T^{cb|a})$    (1)

$T_2^{abc}=P_{a,b,c}  T^{ab|c} = \frac{1}{3}(T^{ab|c} + T^{bc|a} + T^{ca|b})$   (2)

Now $T_1 + T_2 \neq T$ as is clear. However when I project each component using the young symmetrisers associated with the factors of the tensor product, in this case it is $P_{a,b}$ I get T back. That is

$T = P_{a,b}(T_1 + T_2) $
Explicitly,
$P_{a,b} T_1^{abc} = \frac{2}{3} T^{ab|c} + \frac{1}{3}(T^{cb|a} - T^{ca|b})$,

Therefore,
$P_{a,b}(T_1^{abc} + T_2^{abc}) =  \frac{2}{3} T^{ab|c} + \frac{1}{3}(T^{cb|a} - T^{ca|b})+ \frac{1}{3}(T^{ab|c} + T^{bc|a} + T^{ca|b})  = T^{ab|c}$.

Is this relationship true in general i,e suppose I have a tensor product which I write as $T^{\lambda_1|\lambda_2}$ where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ denote the factors belonging to irreps corresponding to the Standard tableaux. Then is the following relationship TRUE, and how do I prove this?

$T^{\lambda_1|\lambda_2} = P_{\lambda_1}P_{\lambda_2}\times$(irreducible components we get by using young symmetrisers generated by LRR and acting on $T^{\lambda_1|\lambda_2}$). In short I want to know if the component of this tensor product living in the irreducible rep characterised by the tableau $\nu$ generated by LRR is,

$\mathbf{P_{\lambda_1}P_{\lambda_2} T_{\nu}}?$

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/874778/11127 Dear user40469. In general, it is frown upon to cross-post simultaneously, because it may waste potential answerer's time. As a minimum OP should mention the cross-post (on both sites!). The preferred procedure is to not cross-post, and if the post hasn't received an acceptable answer after, say, a couple of days, then OP could flag for migration.

Comment: I am sorry I was not aware of this practice. This question straddles between pure math and physics..

Comment: First comment, the phenomenon you observed exists even for a trivial tensor product when you have tensor product of an irreducible tensor $T^A$ given in anti-symmetric basis, as in your example, and a trivial scalar tensor. Then if you apply Young symmetrizer in the form (SA) you will change the basis from antisymmetric to symmetric. Applying in another order (AS) does nothing.

Comment: So, the relatioship is true in general, but of course (SA)T will never be equal (AS)T for some tensor T, which is not a scalar, so please compare, expand or do anything else always in the same basis, symmetric or anti-symmetric, or some else basis.

Comment: Thanks @John I am afraid you may have misunderstood what I was asking. Say I have a tensor $1^p \otimes 1^p $ in your notation $a[p]|b[p]$ one of the basis tensors corresponding to the irreps is $a[p]b[k]|b[p-k]$ another one would be $a[p-1]b[p+1]|ab[p-k-1]$ If i antisymmetrise both of these tensors in a and b I see that they are proportional. But how do I show this in general? Would you some idea as to how I can prove this result?

Comment: Ok, let's try one more time to understand. I do not understand your/my notation a little bit. If the tensor is $a[p]|b[p]$ then the projection is $a[p-k]b[k]|b[p]$ while what you wrote does not have $p$ indices on both sides.

Comment: Ok, Let me make myself clear. I have a tensor product of the following type $1^p \otimes 1^p$, I express this tensor by $T^{a[p]|b[p]}$. I want to find the decomposition into irreducibles now. so for example one of them is given by $a[p]b[k],b[p-k]$, so this one is not explicitly antisymmetric in b's. So I would use an antisymmetric projector acting on all b's. OK, now $a[p]b[k],b[p-k]$ is ONE of the basis tensors in this irreducible subspace. There are others for example, $a[p-1]b[k+1],ab[p-k-1]$, now both a's and b's are not antisymmetric but I antisymmetrise a's, and b's seperately.. contd.

Comment: It turns out that when using the anti-symmetric projectors for a's and b's both of them are proportional. My question is, Is this result general, that is when we have tensor products of more complicated tableaux. Is this clear enough? Thanks a lot for your persistence and please also have a look at this post of mine, where I have asked this question in an equivalent but more concrete way..http://math.stackexchange.com/q/875805/

Comment: Ok, I got it. The thing is that the two tensors are identically the same. Remember that $a[p+k],ab[p-k-1]\equiv0$, which is a Young symmetry property that tells us that the tensor has $[p+k,k]$-diagram. Now we can use this defining property to prove that $a[p-1]b[k+1],ab[p-k-1]$ is proportional to $a[p+k],ab[p-k-1]$. Indeed, $a[p-1]b[k+1],ab[p-k-1]$ is almost a Young condition if we add $a[p][b[k],b]b[p-k-1]$, where I antisymmetrize $[b[k],b]$, we get zero, so the two tensors are identically the same. Ok?

Comment: To avoid doublecounting you need to order indices. For example, you can try alphabetical order, i.e. to have as many $a$'s in front of $b$'s as you can, etc. Somehow what you see is a little bit more complicated example than the question how to distinguish $\epsilon_{abcd}$ and $\epsilon_{bacd}$, where $\epsilon$ is rank-four anti-symmetric. You know the answer - to order indices.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand and agree with everything you say I have done the calculation myself. What I need is a proof for the most general case when we have tensor product with complicated factors corresponding to complicated Young tableaux, does'nt matter in symmetric or anti-symmetric presentation. Am I making myself clear? P.S: thanks to your help we are on the verge of finishing a physics paper, I would like to acknowledge your help if you can kindly send me your details (If that is Ok with you ofcourse)

Comment: Ok, but what exactly you need to prove? from very general properties of tensor products you know that given reducible tensor can be decomposed into irreducibles. Irreducible tensors will contribute according to the multiplicity they have (in your example it is always one, but in general it can be greater). So you cannot have the number of irreducible tensors of some type be greater (or less) than the multiplicty. The rest is how to write all this with indices, which can be ambigous unless you order indices in some way. You can refer to stackexchange, but it is ok for me not to do that :)

Comment: "So you cannot have the number of irreducible tensors of some type be greater (or less) than the multiplicty. " You are refering about young diag's. My question is, Ok I know how to find decomposition into irreducible vector spaces $V = W_1 \oplus W_2 \dots$ now, if $v\in V$ is given tensor, then it can be expressed as $v = w_1 +w_2+\dots$ with $w_1 \in W_1, w_2 \in W_2$ etc.. I can know about what type of irrep each $W_i$ is, but I also need to find the actual component $w_1$ living in W1.

Comment: If the multiplicity is greater than one than there is no canonical way of indentifying tensors of the same symmetry type, you have a linear subspace corresponding to a given Young diagram and the dimension of this space is multiplicity. All bases in this linear space are equivally good. If the case is so simple that the mupltiplicity is always one, then the problem is just to order indices (like in the example you gave when two tensors are identically the same after using Young properties).